# Traceroute behind a Carrier-Grade NAT (IP address 100.64.0.0/10)

Tags: nat, traceroute, icmp

Is it possibile that a Carrier-Grade NAT blocks all incoming ICMP messages?

Trying a traceroute from an IP address belonging to the range 100.64.0.0/10 it doesn't detect any hop, neither the first one.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly normal. You should try tracerouting using a different protocol than ICMP, which is quite often blocked. People do this with UDP, TCP Syn,and so on.  But the name of these programs depends on the OS you are using.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Is it really? What's the justification for blocking it?

Comment: You may try googling `icmp attacks`...

Comment: @phk: Paranoid network administrators.

Comment: I tried with TCP and UDP, my question was about incoming ICMP messages, I guess they are not received.